# TikTok Login Kit web flow - keep getting Redirect URI error (code 10006)

Tags: javascript, tiktok

I'm having an issue getting Login Kit to work. Similar to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699545/tiktok-login-kit-illegal-redirect-link) I have the correct redirect domain listed in tiktok settings and the redirect_uri is basically just "domain/tiktok" but no matter what I do I get the same error message:

[image]

Below is my backend code - it's basically exactly the same as what is listed in the tiktok docs. Any help on this would be much appreciated!

```
const CLIENT_KEY = 'my_key'
const DOMAIN = 'dev.mydomain.com'
const csrfState = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
res.cookie('csrfState', csrfState, { maxAge: 60000 });
const redirect = encodeURIComponent(`https://${DOMAIN}/tiktok`)

let url = 'https://www.tiktok.com/auth/authorize/';

url += '?client_key=' + CLIENT_KEY;
url += '&scope=user.info.basic,video.list';
url += '&response_type=code';
url += '&redirect_uri=' + redirect;
url += '&state=' + csrfState;

res.redirect(url);
```

**UPDATE 8/13/2022**

I submitted the app for review and was approved so the status is now "Live in production" instead of "staging". The issue is still there - still showing error message no matter what domain / callback URL I use

**UPDATE 8/16/2022**

OK so I've made *some* progress on this.

First off - I was able to get the authentication/login screen to finally show up. I realized to do this you need to:

1. Make sure that the status of your app is "Live in production" and not "Staging". Even though when you create a new app you may see client_key and client_secret show up don't let that fool you - Login Kit WILL NOT WORK unless your app is submitted and approved
2. The redirect_uri you include in your server flow must match EXACTLY to whatever value you entered in "Registered domains" in the Settings page. So if you entered "dev.mydomain.com" in Settings then redirect_uri can only be "dev.mydomain.com" not "dev.mydomain.com/tiktok".

I think I might know what the issue is. My guess is that before - on the Settings page you had to enter the FULL redirect URL (not just the domain) and whatever redirect uri was included in the authorization query was checked against this value which was saved in TikTok's database (whatever was entered in the Settings page when path/protocol were allowed). At some point recently, the front-end business logic was changed such that you could only enter a domain (e.g., mydomain.com) on the Settings page without any protocols - however TikTok's backend logic was never updated so during the Login flow they are still checking against an EXACT match for whatever was saved in their DB as the redirect uri - this would explain why an app that was previously using the API with a redirect uri that DOES include protocols (e.g., for Later.com their redirect uri is https://app.later.com/users/auth/tiktok/callback) continues to work and why for any app attempting to save redirect WITH protocols are getting the error message screen. My gut feeling is telling me that the error is not on my part and this is actually a bug on TikTok's API - my guess is it can be addressed either by changing the front-end on the Settings page to allow for path/protocols (I think this is the ideal approach) or to change their backend so that any redirect uri is checked such that it must include 1 of the listed redirect domains.

I've been emailing with the TikTok team - their email is tiktokplatform@tiktok.com - and proposed the two solutions I mentioned above. I suggest if you're having the same issue you email them as well and maybe even link this StackOverflow question so that maybe it will get higher priority if enough people message them about it.

If you're looking for a shot-term hack I'd recommend creating a dedicated app on AWS or Heroku with a clean domain (e.g., https://mydomain-tiktok.herokuapp.com) and then redirect to either your dev or production environment by appending a prefix to the "state" query (e.g., "dev_[STATE_ID]"). I'll just reiterate I consider this a very "hacky" approach handling callbacks and would definitely not want to use something like this in production.

Comment: Same thing here... And I've tried a lot of things.

Comment: This is a standard OAuth error, I don't think there's anything TikTok special about it. If they say the url is not the same, the it's not the same. It has to match to the dot: protocol (http/https), www, trailing slash, everything. Callback url should be included in either the url you make initial request with or in this error page url. Find it and compare that it's correct

Comment: You say "correct domain listed" but I'm pretty sure they ask you for a complete redirect url not just the domain

Comment: "I'm pretty sure they ask you for a complete redirect url not just the domain" -> this is incorrect. the Redirect domain section of the Login Kit in developer portal explicitly says "Domain should not contain http/https or path".  If you try to include a path (like www.domain.com/tiktok/redirect) or even a port number (like www.domain.com:8080) then you will see an error message: "Enter a valid domain without protocols (Example: tiktok.com)" and then won't be able to save changes.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm experiencing the same issue. I tried to add the Webhook kit, because there is a Callback URL to insert and people mentioned, that it should be filled in order to make it work. But it hasn't helped me. Also, I did "Test" on that URL inside Tiktok and it was successful, but when trying to do it in the integration, the callback is not called.

Comment: How do you get the app to be "live in production" without it working? Feels like a chicken-and-egg problem. I've just submitted my app now with nothing deployed to production because obviously I cannot deploy something that doesn't work at all. It also appears that your development and actual account is not the same, so it won't even know that you own the app you're trying to test. It's total nonsense.

Comment: has anyone got the redirect_uri issues resolved on staging? nonsense this thing already

Comment: So my app status is "live in production" now, as well I have added login kit as a product in it, and approved the url domain also. now im still getting redirect_uri error, I have tried giving both same and with path uri as in login kit setting and in the endpoint API but in both cases I am getting redirect_uri error. also its annoying to submit app for review after every little changes.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the integration worked after doing following steps:

*In TikTok developers page:*

1. Like [@eugene-blinn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12472878/eugene-blinn) said: make sure your app is in **Live in production** status (I couldn't find anything in the documentation about why **Staging** apps don't work);
2. Add the **Login Kit** product to your app and set the **Redirect domain** field with your host domain, for example: `mywebsite.com`.

*In your code:*

3. From my tests, I could add whanever url path I wanted, the only constraint was that the domain should match with step 2. So, yes, you can add `https://mywebsite.com/whatever/path/you/want` in `redirect_url` parameter.

That's it. It should work with these 3 steps.

Additionally, I got other issue related to use specific features in the `scope` property (like upload or read videos, etc), so here the solution as well:

Only add **Video Kit** product to the TikTok app and set `video.upload` or `video.list` in the `scope` authorize request won't work unless you also [add the **TikTok API** product in your TikTok app as well](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/scopes-overview/). Btw, it neeeds to be approved too.

Answer (score 2):

TikTok fixed the bug that resulted in URL mismatch with redirect domain from working. However, they fixed it only for paths (e.g., /auth/tiktok) but PORT additions still result in an error - so [www.domain.com:8080/auth/tiktok](http://www.domain.com:8080/auth/tiktok) won't work but [www.domain.com/auth/tiktok](http://www.domain.com/auth/tiktok) WILL work

**UPDATE 10/3/2022**

Got the following response directly from TikTok engineering team:

*At this point, we only support production integrations with TikTok for Developers and require that you have a URL without port number. However, we understand from your communication that this makes it harder for you to build, test, and iterate your integration with us. Unfortunately, at this time, we do not have a timeline for when this additional support for development servers will be added. We request that you only redirect to URLs without port numbers. Thank you for the feedback.*

Comment: Should my app status still be `Live in production` ? as the problem still the same for me (currently my app has staging status)

Comment: is there no way to do this localhost?  Im just testing here.  I have also tried with ngrok and getting the same redirect uri error.

Answer (score 0):

The frontend of the developer's dashboard still rejects protocol and path in validation. However, the backend skips the path validation.
To be able to update the "Redirect domain" simply:

- Open dev tools in chrome and go to the "Network" tab.
- Clic on "Save changes" button on the dashboard.
- Right clic on the "publish" request that appeared and copy as cURL.
- Modify the "redirect_domains" field in the request before pasting it in the terminal.

I believe the app still needs to be approved and in production to get it to work. I'm still waiting for approval and it has been a couple of weeks.

[image]

---

**UPDATE 9/17/2022**

Just like [@mauricio-ribeiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3973376/mauricio-ribeiro), my app worked after it was approved to production. Setting up the redirect domain without path and scheme works just fine.

Comment: doesn't work, even though the server returns 200, the value is not saved, apart from that, tiktok apparently returns access_token instead of an id_token, which is a totally different thing, I suspect some junior devs were given a task to implement oauth and, obviously, they failed.

Comment: Hi, I'm also facing a same issue. my Apps status still "staging". i'm testing it on my local combine with ngork got. but when i test it on my postman. it works. i still confuse how to reproduse from my postman to my site. i'm using laravel 9 to test it right now

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my solution:

1.- In my TikTok App dashboard, the “redirect_uri” is: mydomain.com, without http/https and without path (/my-redirect-url). Also you can add subdomains using this rule

2.- In my code, I have to add http or https to the redirect_uri, and feel free to use path (/my-redirect-uri)

I hope this help you