# TikTok authorization with ngrok

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, tiktok, tiktok-api

I am trying to test tiktok authorization using ngrok since it doesn't seem to want to let me use localhost.

I have configured the redirect uri and saved it

[image]

I am using the following request

> https://open-api.tiktok.com/platform/oauth/connect/?client_key=[REDACTED]&scope=user.info.basic&response_type=code&redirect_uri=dcd4-86-52-89-221.ngrok.io&state=xxxxx

have also tried adding https

> https://open-api.tiktok.com/platform/oauth/connect/?client_key=[REDACTED]&scope=user.info.basic&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://dcd4-86-52-89-221.ngrok.io&state=xxxxx

If i am not logged in to my TikTok account then it will pop up with the please login so i know its working that far. It knows the client_key is valid.  However once i log in it gives me a redirect uri error.

[image]

The thing is its a redirect domain they are looking for so its not, as if i could have the port wrong or the ending path wrong.   I am sending the same domain that i have requested.

How do I set an Ngrok redirect uri for tiktok so i can test this locally?  This should just work im a little confused as to why it doesn't.

Im wondering if it takes time for them to pick up new redirect uri's.

Its defiantly failing on the validation of the redirect uri because i can see that its not sent anything to Ngrok

[image]

## update

twenty five hours later after setting. serval redirect domains including one to my main website.  I have not be able to get it to accept any redirect Uris.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the same issue which is described in this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73338099/tiktok-login-kit-web-flow-keep-getting-redirect-uri-error-code-10006) it is the problem with the TikTok developer app which is not submitted and approved. Once you have approved the app, your case should work fine.

Comment: you need to have an app approved before you can even begin testing with it?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes... to be even worse, they do not accept ports in the URL.

Comment: and every day when you are developing you get a new url?  does it have to be approved again.

Comment: It is really hard to get approval, there are a lot of requirements from their side, one of that is also the official Website URL... There is no playground mode.

Comment: I wonder if I would set it to my website then configure a redirect