# Tiktok Direct post API - Redirect_URI issue

Tags: python, oauth, tiktok-api

I would like to get the authorization code from tiktok's API but everytime I face the same Error.

[image]

```
Auth 127.0.0.1 - - "GET /auth/ HTTP/1.1" 301
Response
https://www.tiktok.com/v2/auth/authorize/?client_key=<client_key>&scope=user.info.basic&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8080%2Fcallback%2F&state=344a13d1f932a73517ea31abaf98cd66&code_challenge=%7B%27d85aea26bf0fded67f98fa487aab480061ca0d00786dbd064399fe93d06b5704%27%7D&code_challenge_method=S256&error=invalid_request&error_type=redirect_uri
```

**PS** Ii am using staging keys not production keys.

**RedirectURI** 127.0.0.1 - - "GET /callback/ HTTP/1.1" 200 **the same as the tiktok's app Redirect_uri**

i made this code based on the tiktok's [Doc](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/login-kit-desktop/)
**Code**

```
def getAuthorizationURL():
    AUTHORIZE_URL = 'https://www.tiktok.com/v2/auth/authorize/'

    csrf_state = secrets.token_hex(16)

    params = {
        'client_key': Auth.tiktok_client_key,
        'scope': 'user.info.basic',
        'response_type': 'code',
        'redirect_uri': Auth.tiktok_redirect_uri, #"http://127.0.0.1:8080/callback/"
        'state': csrf_state,
        'code_challenge':__generateRandomString(64),
        'code_challenge_method':'S256'    }

    url = AUTHORIZE_URL + '?' + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
    
    return url
```

I contacted their support but they didn't respond yet and, unfortunately, I couldn't find anything online.

Comment: maybe use `print( Auth.tiktok_redirect_uri )` to see what you really have as `redirect_url` and compare it with settings on page `TikTok Development` (after you login)

Comment: documentation shows `redirect_url` with port `:3455` but you show with `:8000`. And this can make different. Maybe TikTok needs exactly `:3455` when you use `127.0.0.1`. If you want to use page on own server then you may need real IP (external IP) instead of `127.0.0.1`. But if you run page on local (home) computer then this may need changes in routers of your Internet Provider - (because it may block access from internet's client to local server - for security reason) - and this can make problem because you don't have access ti routers of your Internet Providers

Comment: @furas for your 1st comment here's the decoded redirect_uri generated in the auth endpoint redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/callback/ which is the same as the desktop redirect_uri of the app. the 3455 port is just an example of a valid url but i tried use it too and it didn't work The following are some examples of valid redirect URIs: http://127.0.0.1:*/callback/ https://127.0.0.1:3455/callback/ but thanks i tried to make my app public by forwarding my public ip but unfortunately tiktok only accept localhost or loopback addresses.

Comment: [javascript - TikTok Login Kit web flow - keep getting Redirect URI error (code 10006) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73338099/tiktok-login-kit-web-flow-keep-getting-redirect-uri-error-code-10006)

Comment: @furas thank you for your help i already read this question and i submitted the app for review but they didn't approve the 1st time and yeah finally their support have sent me a message back ***It looks like your application is still in staging. We will need to review and approve your application before you can proceed.***